# Ubuntu 18.04 lts Sharing File in Windows AD

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to create a folder running Ubuntu 18.04 lts desktop in order to share with Windows machines.  I seem to have everything right...Ubuntu pc is on Windows AD, samba service installed, created folder and it is shared.  From windows pc i can enter \ubuntuIPaddress\ and I see printers but cannot see the folder I have created.